# Relaciones mysql

Tags: mysql

tengo un pequeño problema y me surgen dudas.
Tomando este texto como ejemplo:

"cliente contiene el establecimiento, que a su vez el establecimiento contiene los lotes"

Mi intento es este:

```
create table lotes (
id_lote int auto_increment primary key,
desc_lote varchar(50) not null
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table establecimientos(
id_establecimiento int auto_increment primary key,
desc_establecimiento varchar(50) not null,
id_lote int not null,
foreign key fk_id_lote(id_lote) references lotes(id_lote)
on update cascade
on delete restrict
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table clientes(
id_cliente int auto_increment primary key,
desc_cliente varchar(50) not null,
id_establecimiento int not null,
foreign key fk_id_establecimiento(id_establecimiento) 
references establecimientos(id_establecimiento)
on update cascade
on delete restrict
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Inserto un lote, un establecimiento, un cliente y todo va bien.
Inserto otro establecimiento e intento agregarlo al mismo cliente, y me dice clave duplicada.

Mi duda es si tengo bien las pks, creo que en clientes, la pk debería ser id_cliente y id_establecimiento y a su vez id_establecliento es fk. Ya que un cliente puede contener muchos establecimientos.
Mismo con lotes y establecimientos?
Estoy en lo correcto?

Muchas gracias

Comment: La estructura está bien, pero cómo estás haciendo la segunda inserción del establecimiento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu esquema funcionará bien, siempre y cuando no repitas el `id_cliente` en la inserción.

Ahora bien, si en la tabla `clientes` deben haber filas repetidas con el mismo `id_cliente` y un mismo cliente puede tener varios establecimientos asociados, necesitarás **una tercera tabla que relacione clientes y establecimientos**. De ese modo en la tabla `clientes`  tendrás **solamente** los datos del cliente: id, nombre, teléfono, etc y en la tabla que podrás llamar `clientes-departamentos` tendrás varios id de clientes repetidos y cada uno con su `id_departamento` correspondiente.

En este ejemplo la última consulta `INSERT` acepta el mismo departamento, pero para distintos clientes, si la relación es *uno a uno* el diseño de la tabla puede quedar como lo tienes ahora, pero si la relación es *muchos a muchos*, o sea, que en un departamento pueden haber varios clientes y/o viceversa, es mejor una tercera tabla que contenga solamente dos columnas `id_cliente, id_departamento` y la clave primaria sería la combinación de ambas columnas, para evitar que haya datos repetidos que a la larga harán crecer tu BD innecesariamente y la harán más lenta, más difícil de consultar, administrar, mantener...

Para este caso, yo propongo que hagas tu esquema como explico en el último apartado, titulado **EJEMPLO PROPUESTO**.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21e15f/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table lotes (
id_lote int auto_increment primary key,
desc_lote varchar(50) not null
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO lotes (id_lote, desc_lote) VALUES (1,"desc1");

create table establecimientos(
id_establecimiento int auto_increment primary key,
desc_establecimiento varchar(50) not null,
id_lote int not null,
foreign key fk_id_lote(id_lote) references lotes(id_lote)
on update cascade
on delete restrict
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO establecimientos 
(id_establecimiento,desc_establecimiento,id_lote)
VALUES (1,"desc est 1",1), (2,"desc est 2",1);



create table clientes(
id_cliente int auto_increment primary key,
desc_cliente varchar(50) not null,
id_establecimiento int not null,
foreign key fk_id_establecimiento(id_establecimiento) 
references establecimientos(id_establecimiento)
on update cascade
on delete restrict
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO clientes (id_cliente,desc_cliente,id_establecimiento)
VALUES
(1,"desc cliente 1", 1),
(2,"desc cliente 2", 2);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM clientes
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21e15f/2/0)**:

```
| id_cliente |   desc_cliente | id_establecimiento |
|------------|----------------|--------------------|
|          1 | desc cliente 1 |                  1 |
|          2 | desc cliente 2 |                  2 |
```

## EJEMPLO PROPUESTO

Observa este ejemplo con una tabla asociativa. Aquí podrás repetir en la tabla `cliente_establecimiento` el campo `id_cliente` controlando que no haya dos veces el mismo cliente-establecimiento, estableciendo en dicha tabla una pk compuesta por los campos que son clave foránea de cada tabla de la relación.

Luego haces la consultad mediante `JOINS`, como se muestra en el ejemplo, o con cualquier otro de los tipos de JOIN existentes, según tus necesidades.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21e15f/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table lotes (
id_lote int auto_increment primary key,
desc_lote varchar(50) not null
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO lotes (id_lote, desc_lote) VALUES (1,"desc1");

create table establecimientos(
id_establecimiento int auto_increment primary key,
desc_establecimiento varchar(50) not null,
id_lote int not null,
foreign key fk_id_lote(id_lote) references lotes(id_lote)
on update cascade
on delete restrict
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO establecimientos 
(id_establecimiento,desc_establecimiento,id_lote)
VALUES 
(1,"desc est 1",1), 
(2,"desc est 2",1),
(3,"desc est 3",1);

create table clientes(
id_cliente int auto_increment primary key, desc_cliente varchar(50) not null,
id_establecimiento int not null,
foreign key fk_id_establecimiento(id_establecimiento) 
references establecimientos(id_establecimiento)
on update cascade
on delete restrict
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO clientes (id_cliente,desc_cliente,id_establecimiento)
VALUES
(1,"desc cliente 1", 1),
(2,"desc cliente 2", 2);

create table clientes_establecimientos(
  id_cliente int,
  id_establecimiento int,
  primary key(id_cliente,id_establecimiento)
 )ENGINE=InnoDB;

 INSERT INTO clientes_establecimientos(id_cliente,id_establecimiento)
 VALUES
 (1,1),
 (1,2),
 (2,1),
 (2,3);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT c.id_cliente,  c.desc_cliente, e.id_establecimiento 
FROM clientes_establecimientos ce
  LEFT JOIN clientes c 
    ON ce.id_cliente = c.id_cliente
  LEFT JOIN establecimientos e
    ON ce.id_establecimiento = e.id_establecimiento
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21e15f/2/0)**:

```
| id_cliente |   desc_cliente | id_establecimiento |
|------------|----------------|--------------------|
|          1 | desc cliente 1 |                  1 |
|          1 | desc cliente 1 |                  2 |
|          2 | desc cliente 2 |                  1 |
|          2 | desc cliente 2 |                  3 |
```

Comment: entonces tu sugieres que haya una tabla clientesxestablecimientos que contenga (id_cliente, id_establecimiento) ambos fk y sin pk?

Gracias

Comment: Sí en lo primero, no en lo segundo. Pues en esa tabla asociativa **la pk sería la combinación de ambas columnas (id_cliente, id_establecimiento)**, ya que el mismo cliente no puede estar dos veces en el mismo establecimiento.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: @GAL De nada. He actualizado la respuesta, poniendo al final un **EJEMPLO PROPUESTO** en el que se muestra la tabla asociativa y un ejemplo de consulta para traer los datos haciendo `JOIN` en las tablas. Saludos.

Comment: Una pregunta más, también debería hacer una tabla relacional entre establecimientos y lotes? Ya que 1 establecimiento puede contener varios lotes.

Gracias

Comment: Las tablas asociativas hay que usarlas **siempre** que haya una relación _varios a varios_ (varios establecimientos pueden tener varios lotes y al revés). Aquí la única forma en que no usarías tablas asociativas, aunque yo las uso casi siempre en estos casos, es si, **un lote no puede estar en varios establecimientos** pues en este caso poniendo un `id_establecimiento` en la tabla `lotes` ya tienes la relación hecha. Pero si un lote puede figurar en varios establecimientos, la respuesta es clara: **tabla asociativa**.